# How C++ compiler handles these basic and similar functions

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm reviewing the practice final for a class and one question is -

How will the compiler handle each of the following calls? Assume max has not been referenced anywhere else in your code.

(a) max(3, 7)

(b) max(3.0, 7.0)

(c) max(3, 7.0)

I'm completely clueless about compiler things and the stuff I researched was way beyond this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: A hint: It has to do with the type of the inputs.

Comment: I really hope that's not the complete test question. If it is I hope someone deletes the test with malice and contempt.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will find the *most suitable* method that can be called from the overloads based on the passed parameter values. If none found, error will popup. for example when calling `max(3,6)`, since both parameters are of `int` type, if there is a method named `max` present which takes such parameter, compiler will call it. If not, and if there is a method that takes parameter to which passed values can be converted ( ex. `max(double,double))`, then it will be called since `int` is *implicitly convertible* to `double`. If no such method exists, error. Learn [function overloading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm)

Comment: If this is talking about the standard one, there's also template argument deduction that comes into play first.

Comment: @chris This is likely what I expect the test is talking about, hence the point about the compiler not having hit a ``max`` method before. I'm not 100% if having instantiated a template for the ``int,int`` case before would cause the ``int,double`` method to use that, or if it would simply throw an ambiguous cast error (but I suspect the latter).

Comment: @aruisdante, Template argument deduction would fail because the same `T` is deduced as two different types. That would result in a compiler error. As long as you haven't got a non-template one that matches anyway.

Comment: @chris, you are right, function template will fail if the argument type(s) do not match exactly (even if the actual types are convertible). And about my reply, to a learner who does not understand regular overloaded method resolution, explain template would be hard for me.